How to creat a Mesh Size Field in GMSH to increase the size of the mesh from a circle hole
My mesh is a simple square with a circle hole and I want to learn how to have a size field that increases my mesh size around the circle hole created. This is the geo file to be implemented on gmsh for creating a mesh withou the size function :
R = 0.25; // hole radius
L = 1.00; // lenght

l = 0.01;

// Define points for the square

Point(1) = {0, 0, 0, l};

Point(2) = {L, 0, 0, l};

Point(3) = {L, L, 0, l};

Point(4) = {0, L, 0, l};

// Define lines for the square

Line(1) = {1, 2};

Line(2) = {2, 3};

Line(3) = {3, 4};

Line(4) = {4, 1};

// Define the line loop for the square

Line Loop(1) = {1, 2, 3, 4};

// Define points for the circular hole

Point(5) = {0.5*L, 0.5*L, 0, l};

Point(6) = {0.5*L + R, 0.5*L, 0, l};

Point(7) = {0.5*L, 0.5*L + R, 0, l};

Point(8) = {0.5*L - R, 0.5*L, 0, l};

Point(9) = {0.5*L, 0.5*L - R, 0, l};

// Define circles for the hole

Circle(10) = {6, 5, 7};

Circle(11) = {7, 5, 8};

Circle(12) = {8, 5, 9};

Circle(13) = {9, 5, 6};

// Define the line loop for the hole

Line Loop(2) = {10, 11, 12, 13};

// Define the plane surface for the square and exclude the circular hole

Plane Surface(1) = {1, 2};

// Generate the mesh

Mesh 2;

The desired result is :

I am new to the size field function, I tried some options but none of them worked as desired.
